# tkinker - Can i avoid looping through the entire program?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, label, updates

I am trying to make a graphing calculator in python using tkinter. I have a label made to show the equation the user is graphing, and i want to update the label every time a button is clicked. I'm very new with tkinter and one of the problems I'm facing is that when the program loops, it refreshes a list that i have to it's initial conditions. Is there a way use the tkinter mainloop to loop through only a portion of the program so that my list stops refreshing? Thank you very much! I'm trying my best!

```
from tkinter import *
import math
mat=["hello"]
root = Tk()

height=400
width=420

buttonframe=Frame(root)
buttonframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)

canvas = Canvas(height=height, width=width, bg="black")
canvas.pack(anchor=NW)


w=Label(buttonframe,bg="white",text="y = " + (''.join(mat)))
w.grid(row=0,column=3)


def button0():
    mat.append("0")
def button1():
    mat.append("1")
def button2():
    mat.append("2")
def button3():
    mat.append("3")
def button4():
    mat.append("4")
def button5():
    mat.append("5")
def button6():
    mat.append("6")
def button7():
    mat.append("7")
def button8():
    mat.append("8")
def button9():
    mat.append("9")
def buttonsin(var):
    mat.append("(math.sin("+ var +"))")
def buttoncos(var):
    mat.append("(mat.cos("+ var + "))")
def buttontan():
    mat.append("(mat.tan("+ var + "))")

for x in range(-(int(width/2)),(int(width/2))):
    x1=(width/2)+x
    x2=(width/2)+x+1
    y = (height/2)-(math.sin(x))
    y2= (height/2)-(math.sin(x+1))
    canvas.create_line(x1,y,x2,y2,fill="green",dash=(5,5))

#buttons
button1 = Button(buttonframe, text="0", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button0)
button1.grid(row=1,column=3)

button2 = Button(buttonframe, text="1", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button1)
button2.grid(row=1,column=4)

button3 = Button(buttonframe,text="2", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button2)
button3.grid(row=1,column=5)

button4 = Button(buttonframe,text="sine", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=buttonsin)
button4.grid(row=1,column=6)

button5 = Button(buttonframe,text="cosine", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=buttoncos)
button5.grid(row=1,column=7)

button6 = Button(buttonframe,text="tangent", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=buttontan)
button6.grid(row=1,column=8)

#next row
button7 = Button(buttonframe,text="3", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button3)
button7.grid(row=2,column=3)

button1 = Button(buttonframe, text="4", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button4)
button1.grid(row=2,column=4)

button2 = Button(buttonframe, text="5", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button5)
button2.grid(row=2,column=5)

button3 = Button(buttonframe,text="x^2", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button3.grid(row=2,column=6)

button4 = Button(buttonframe,text="x^y", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button4.grid(row=2,column=7)

button5 = Button(buttonframe,text="sqrt", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button5.grid(row=2,column=8)

#next row
button6 = Button(buttonframe,text="6", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button6)
button6.grid(row=3,column=3)

button7 = Button(buttonframe,text="7", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button7)
button7.grid(row=3,column=4)

button5 = Button(buttonframe,text="8", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button8)
button5.grid(row=3,column=5)

button6 = Button(buttonframe,text="button6", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button6.grid(row=3,column=6)

button7 = Button(buttonframe,text="button7", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button7.grid(row=3,column=7)

button1 = Button(buttonframe, text="button", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button1.grid(row=3,column=8)

#next row
button2 = Button(buttonframe, text="9", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue",command=button9)
button2.grid(row=4,column=3)

button3 = Button(buttonframe,text="+", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button3.grid(row=4,column=4)

button4 = Button(buttonframe,text="-", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button4.grid(row=4,column=5)

button5 = Button(buttonframe,text="button5", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button5.grid(row=4,column=6)

button6 = Button(buttonframe,text="button6", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button6.grid(row=4,column=7)

button6 = Button(buttonframe,text="button6", width=10,height=2,bg="light blue")
button6.grid(row=4,column=8)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is actually the problem? Not sure what you mean by loop only a portion of your program. `mainloop` refers to the event loop, that's not looping over your code.

Comment: i don't know, just the mat = [] at the beginning is being constantly cleared even as i append things to it, I'm pretty sure because I'm looping over that line, which initializes it, tell me if im wrong?

Comment: why isn't my list being updated then? please?

Comment: mainloop does not loop through _any_ portion of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mainloop` does not loop through your code. Your program is executed once. `mainloop` is simply a loop that processes events in a queue, it doesn't continuously try to run your code.

The problem is not that the list isn't being updated. The list *is* being updated. You're not doing anything to cause that list to be displayed. When you configure a label to display the list, you are ultimately giving it a static string. You need to explicitly reset the string on the label.

```
def button0():
    mat.append("0")
    w.configure(text="y = " + (''.join(mat)))
```

Comment: Aaaahhh!!! Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!! Im very new at this and this makes sense!!! Also the other guy was super helpful too!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter's main loop checks for updates like newly triggered events, it does not execute all of your code over and over. The key is not changing the behavior of mainloop, but making sure the initialization code isn't run by the loop.

Try something like this

```
def button9():
  mat.append("9")
  w.config(text="y = " + (''.join(mat)))
```

Comment: Thank you! but making sure the initialization code isn't run by the loop?

Comment: This wording is incorrect. mainloop does not "go through the program checking for updates". It is simply a loop; not a lot different than `while True: process_event()`.

Comment: If thats not the case, then why do you think my list (mat) is not being updated??? @BryanOakley

Comment: How does your mat list actually update your labels? That's the part I'm not seeing. And you;re right Bryan, that was wrong the way it was worded.

Comment: well it seems in the process of debugging i had removes that part, oops... But what it did is it joined the list as a string and displayed it directly in the label

Comment: oh wait no its there! Yeah, sorry, the buttons were appending items to the list, which was then being displayed on the label! :)

Comment: It sounds like the actual problem is that none of your code is being executed in the event loop! Each of your buttons functions would have to update the label for this to work. Do you think mat is being clearing because things aren't showing up on the label, or are you actually printing out the value of mat?

Comment: Oh you are right! is IS being updated, just not showing up on the label! how do i update the label in the button functions? Thank you for knowing what you're doing!

Comment: Well , you beat me to it by a hair haha.

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to create your Tkinter as a class. That way when you need to update values it updates to update the value of class variables that will all exist as long as the instance exists

Comment: You are not addressing the OPs problem by suggesting to use a class. What the OP is trying to do is entirely possible outside of a class he is just going about it in the wrong way.

Comment: ^^^^^^^*****she

Comment: @smaude: Sorry I should leave my comments gender neutral. Force of habit.